# var this.Parent as STP2Main better syntax

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, controls, parent

I have a controll which has the following function if I load the control into form A.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var C = this.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as STP2Main;
        C.DisposeControl(STP_Data.Data.ConfigConfigResource);
    }
```

if i load the control into form B I need this to write this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var C = this.Parent.Parent.Parent as STP2Main;
        C.DisposeControl(STP_Data.Data.ConfigConfigResource);
    }
```

this works. but I really do not like the `this.Parent.Parent...` (up to 5 times Parent) If i set a breakpoint on the `var C` line I see it is pointing to `[STP_Design.STP2Main]` but when I change the function to `var C = STP_Design.STP2Main as STP2Main;` I get an error which says:

'STP_Design.STP2Main' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

How do I get rid of the Parent.Parent.Parent part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parent control is a `Form` you could use

```
var C = this.ParentForm as SomeControlName;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not disposing the parent. I am just calling a function in a different class in the same namespace. That function must use the existing class and not create a new one.

Comment: How has what I have written lead you to belive this code will dispose the parent? It is just avoiding re-writing that ugly code - that is all. I also did not have the information you provided in the above commentso the downvote is harsh. If the parent is a form - you could just use `this.ParentForm` - or devise a method that recursively gets the control you need...

Comment: Sorry, but I did not downvote your comment. I'll check out the this.ParentForm function. The function DisposeControl(this.Parent.Parent.Parent) would dispose the parent, using the code behind that function. Thats where I got that thought. NVM. If you simply change your answer to use this.ParentForm instead of this.Parent.Parent.Parent etc if the parent is a form. This solved my problem. I'll upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not all that hard.  Just keep checking the parent of the the control until you either run out of parents to check, or find one of the proper type.  I've written this to be a bit more general; you can use it for any type of parent (just put it in the generic type) and rather than using a specific action I've provided a parameter for method that is called on the parent form.

```
public static void DisposeMainParent<T>(this Control control, Action<T> disposal)
    where T : Control
{
    Control temp = control;
    T mainControl = null;
    for (Control c = control; c != null && mainControl == null; c = c.Parent)
    {
        mainControl = temp as T;
    }

    if (mainControl != null)
    {
        disposal(mainControl);
    }
}
```